# How to find a value inside MongoDB row

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

Can somebody help me to find out how I can search in an array for a value that is inside?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555336a4cc8eaa1ec8277517"),
    "UUID" : "8be5b625-f556-11e4-84c3-0015179d63a4",
    "ManufacturerUUID" : "412890ed-f552-11e4-84c3-0015179d63a4",
    "ManufacturerSKU" : null,
    "LastChanged" : "2015-05-13 13:14:57",
    "Store" : {
        "Title" : "Synology Disk Station DS214play",
        "Description" : "",
        "Price" : "0",
        "AllowDisplay" : "0",
        "Activated" : "1"
    },
    "Category" : [ 
        "c8a13e5e-2113-4686-ace4-e06d9a94c368", 
        "aab97dc9-af10-4aaa-89f3-e9c9d17f6685"
    ]
}
```

I want to find if the `UUID` in Category matches a category `"UUID"` so that the product matches a category, but my problem right now is I'm not sure how I can search for a `UUID = a category UUID`. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: you can search in array but I don't see any array here.

Comment: "Category" : {
        "c8a13e5e-2113-4686-ace4-e06d9a94c368" : {
            "UUID" : "c8a13e5e-2113-4686-ace4-e06d9a94c368"
        },
        "aab97dc9-af10-4aaa-89f3-e9c9d17f6685" : {
            "UUID" : "aab97dc9-af10-4aaa-89f3-e9c9d17f6685"
        }
    }

Comment: This is not an array. This is a json object. If I have to correct it to make it an array, it would look like this - "Category" : [ { "UUID" : "c8a13e5e-2113-4686-ace4-e06d9a94c368" }, { "UUID" : "aab97dc9-af10-4aaa-89f3-e9c9d17f6685" } ]

Comment: Okay, hmmm thats wirdt becurs i save a array to mongodb, its it not possible to search a object?

Comment: Its difficult with the current structure you have. BTW, I don't understand the point of having value of UUID as keys. If I were you I would probably go with the array thing I mentioned in my previous comment. It make thing a lot more clear and easy.

Comment: Now i have updated to handle in Arrays, can i search inside the array now? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77707/discussion-between-parisnakitakejser-and-abhay-ps).

Comment: Got it, db.getCollection('product').find({Category: "35b448db-f2c9-46e1-aa1a-d8c7899e8a8b"}) :) this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply shoot find query like this -

```
db.getCollection('product').find({Category: "35b448db-f2c9-46e1-aa1a-d8c7899e8a8b"})
```

If you want to find using multiple values then query would look like this -

```
db.getCollection('product').find({Category: { $in : ["35b448db-f2c9-46e1-aa1a-d8c7899e8a8b", "23b448db-f2c9-46e1-aa1a-d8c7899e8a8w"] } })
```